# Why a reference to a reference don't update the original object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reference

Well, I'm making a function to update player's hp over time.

On my NodeJS side, I'm passing the players array to `require('./addHp')(players);` Inside `addHp.js` I have this fully working function:

```
module.exports = function (players) {

  var addHp = setInterval ( function () {
    for (var player in players) {
      var thisPlayer = players[player];
      (thisPlayer.hp < thisPlayer.maxHp) ? //Uggly
         thisPlayer.hp += 10 :             //Uggly
         thisPlayer.hp = thisPlayer.maxHp; //Uggly
    }
  }, 2000);
```

}

But it's really not too easy to read so I've made some changes:

```
module.exports = function (players) {
  var addHp = setInterval ( function () {

    for (var player in players) {
      var thisPlayer = players[player];
      var hp = thisPlayer.hp;
      var maxHp = thisPlayer.maxHp;

      (hp < maxHp) ? hp += 10 : hp = maxHp; //Beautiful

    }
  }, 2000);
}
```

All the proper values are reaching both `hp` and `maxHp`, but when I change the `hp` to 5000, the value of `players[player].hp` won't change. Why? And how can I use it this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't work because `hp` (which is probably a numeric value, and not an object at all) is not attached to any outside object. Your object is a value in the players array (or players object, doesn't really matter), and you need to mutate *that*. There's really no way around this.

With that said, I'd write this a little different:

```
for (var player in players) {
  var p = players[player];
  p.hp = Math.max(p.maxHp, p.hp + 10);
}
```

If `players` is an *Array*, you can even do:

```
for (var player of players) {
  player .hp = Math.max(player .maxHp, player .hp + 10);
}
```

Comment: So, if I reference an OBJECT variable to VAR variable, all changes to VAR will also happen on OBJECT? And, if I reference an NUMBER variable to VAR variable, the VAR will receive the same value as NUMBER but will not propagate changes? Is that right?

Comment: there is not such thing as *VAR variable*. A variable can hold a reference to an object, or a simple "native" value (string, number, boolean...). When a variable holds a reference to an object, mutating that object has a "lasting effect" that can be observer by other variables holding a reference to the same object.

Comment: VAR IS a variable. Sorry, I mean something like var VAR = OBJECT;

Comment: object are shared, numbers and strings are simple static values